# How to set BackgroundImage full page in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

I'm trying to set a background image as full page image but it's being displayed small(even when using inside header.css height: 100% ), I just started learning reactJS, please explain to me how to fix this?

here's an example of what i'm trying to acheive:
https://www.devoncrawford.io/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import headerImg from './images/mountain.jpg';
import './style/header.css'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <div id="header" style={headerStyle}></div>
      <Menu/>  
    </div>


      );
  }
}
var headerStyle ={
  backgroundImage: `url(${headerImg})`
}

export default App;
```

the header.css

```
#header {
height:100%;
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow geekys! You could set `position:absolute;` on the image and set `height:100vh;` and `width:100vw;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position your image absolutely on the page, and make it cover the entire screen with a height of `100vh` and a width of `100vw`.

```
var headerStyle ={
  backgroundImage: `url(${headerImg})`,
  position: 'absolute',
  width: '100vw',
  height: '100vh'
}
```